# Searching a content and alert if

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, greasemonkey

I made a search script which searches for "Hallow" and alerts.

```
var Item = $('td > a:contains("Hallow")').text()
if(Item) {
alert(Item); }
```

This javascript is working for this html:

```
<html><body><div style="Padding:10px;">

            <table width="469" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" border="0">

                        <tbody>
                 <tr valign="top">
                        <td width="313">&nbsp;<img width="11" height="10" src="graphics/Default/Miscellaneous/weight.gif" alt="Yük: 3" title="Yük: 3">&nbsp;

                        <a href="CharacterDetails.asp?action=ViewItemDetails&amp;ItemTypeiD=236&amp;ItemID=100084253&amp;CharacterID=53845">Kovboy çizmeleri</a>                                                                                                                              </td>
                    <td width="140" align="right">  </td>
                </tr>



                    <tr valign="top">
                        <td width="313">&nbsp;<img width="11" height="10" src="graphics/Default/Miscellaneous/weight.gif" alt="Yük: 5" title="Yük: 5">&nbsp;

                        <a href="CharacterDetails.asp?action=ViewItemDetails&amp;ItemTypeiD=168&amp;ItemID=68615745&amp;CharacterID=53845">Halloween Canavar Maskesi</a>


                      </td>
                    <td width="140" align="right">

                    </td>
                </tr>



           </tbody></table>
              <table width="469" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" border="0">
                </table>


  <br>
  <br>
  </div></body></html>
```

---

But sometimes item is secured. And html is like this:

```
     <html><body><div style="Padding:10px;">

                <table width="469" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" border="0">

                            <tbody>

                        <tr valign="top">
                            <td width="313">&nbsp;<img width="11" height="10" src="graphics/Default/Miscellaneous/weight.gif" alt="Yük: 3" title="Yük: 3">&nbsp;

                            <a href="CharacterDetails.asp?action=ViewItemDetails&amp;ItemTypeiD=236&amp;ItemID=100084253&amp;CharacterID=53845">Kovboy çizmeleri</a>                                                                                                                              </td>
                        <td width="140" align="right">  </td>
                    </tr>



                        <tr valign="top">
                            <td width="313">&nbsp;<img width="11" height="10" src="graphics/Default/Miscellaneous/weight.gif" alt="Yük: 5" title="Yük: 5">&nbsp;

                            <a href="CharacterDetails.asp?action=ViewItemDetails&amp;ItemTypeiD=168&amp;ItemID=68615745&amp;CharacterID=53845">Halloween Canavar Maskesi</a>


                          </td>
                        <td width="140" align="right">
Secured
</td>
                    </tr>

                    </tbody></table>
                  <table width="469" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" border="0">
                    </table>


      <br>
      <br>
      </div></body></html>
```

I dont want my javascript to alert me if item is secured.

Function must be like that

```
var Item = $('td > a:contains("Hallow")').text()
var Itemsecured = (A code)
if(Itemsecured) {
}
else {
alert(Item)
}
```

I need the correct version of this code.

And this is important: I have two items, one is secured other is not. Javascript must alert me.

Comment: `<html><head></<html><head></head>` Seriously? That's your markup?

Comment: Why is your code halfway across my screen? And then your Javascript has no indentation at all? If you can't be bothered to make your post legible, then I can't be bothered to answer it... :(

Comment: I know, I have mistakes. I am sorry :(

Comment: @Ahmet: You can use a code beautifier, to help make your code legible.  I like [this one](http://tools.arantius.com/tabifier) because it doesn't try to fix "invalid" code (which can mask the problem for SO questions), just formats it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('td > a:contains("Hallow")').each(function(){
    if($(this).parent().next('td').text() == 'Secured') {
      // actions for secured item
    }
    else {
      alert($(this).text());
    }
});
```

Comment: I thing there is a problem. İt always alert($(this).tex()); ?

Comment: No it's not. alerts: http://jsfiddle.net/FrE9Q/1/ doesn't alert: http://jsfiddle.net/AztEe/ . But you better marking secured items with a css class.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/FrE9Q/2/ This is the real html version. Please help me to edit your code.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NtEyA/ . Note the class="secured" part. You better use approach that Sinetheta recommends.

Comment: Because "Secured" is not equal to "\n\t\t\t\t\tSecured\n\t\t\t\t". There's whitespaces in the td. But forget it. Just use the css class.

Comment: @Hnatt, The OP can't just "use the css class", and he would have the same problem identifying the node if he did.  This is a Greasemonkey application; the OP has no control over the page until it is loaded in the browser.

Comment: @Hnatt, can you help me for using css class? http://jsfiddle.net/FrE9Q/4/ can you improve it by using css class. Because I dont know that well.

Comment: If @Brock Adams is right and HTML is out of your control, then CSS will not help you. Just use indexOf() instead of direct comparison. Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/DwvJU/ . Try if it will work with your Turkish text.

Answer (score 1):

Don't store semantic information in a sibling; add a class.

```
var Contents = $('td:not(".secured") a:contains("Hallow")').text()
if( Contents ) alert( Contents )
```

Comment: This is a Greasemonkey application.  The OP does not control the page generation, nor the server. GM scripts test and modify the page after it has loaded.